# Insert data into table from others three tables yii2

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii2

There are 4 tables - user, holiday, single-events, notifiations_events. I need  to insert data into notifications_events from the other 3 tables. Tables:

```
users:
id
username
password_hash
birthday
status


holidays:
id
month
day
name
description


single-events:
id
date_at
name
description


notifications_events:
id
date_at
type
event_id
message
```

I'm trying this code but it's not working:

```
public function actionInsert()
{
    $model = new NotificationsEvents();
    $model->date_at = (new Query())
        ->select(['single-events.date_at'])
        ->from('single-events')
        ->join('LEFT JOIN', 'user', 'user.birthday');

    $model->event_id = (new Query())
        ->select(['single-events.id'])
        ->from('single-events')
        ->join('LEFT JOIN', 'user', 'user.id');

    $model->save();
}
```

So, I need to get data from the other 3 tables into notifications_events. For example, the event_id field must be equal to holiday.id or user.id, the date_at must be equal to user.birthday, and other dates. In type, you need to enter the type of event, you can use numbers, you can still score on a message. Help make a request. *Desirable on the php yii2 framework*. Although I will be quite ordinary sql.

Comment: looks like you need to add ->scalar() to sub queries
eg: (new Query())
        ->select(['single-events.date_at'])
        ->from('single-events')
        ->join('LEFT JOIN', 'user', 'user.birthday')->scalar();

Comment: I think better solution is to define relation in NotificationsEvents model to SingleEvents. And then use link() method

Comment: maybe, I will try this, thank